# Angular object not displaying in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, oop

I am doing a LinkedInLearning tutorial on Angular and I cannot figure out why my component cannot display data from an object.  I can log the object and see the property fields.  I can display a boolean value but the object properties are not available.

Here is my component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ListingsService } from '../listings.service';
import { Listing } from '../types';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-listing-detail-page',
  templateUrl: './listing-detail-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./listing-detail-page.component.css']
})
export class ListingDetailPageComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoading: boolean = true;
    listing: Listing;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private listingsService: ListingsService,
    
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.listingsService.getListingById(id!).subscribe(l=>{
      this.listing = l;
      console.log(l);
      this.isLoading = false;
    });
    this.listingsService.addViewToListing(id!).subscribe(()=>console.log('Views Updated'));
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML for display:

```
<div class="content-box" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <p>This listing has been viewed {{listing.views}} {{isLoading}} times</p>
    <a routerLink="/listings">
        <button>Back</button>
    </a>
    <h2>Name {{ listing.name }}</h2>
    <p>{{listing.description}}</p>
    <p>${{listing.price}}</p>
    <a routerLink="/contact/{{listing.id}}">
        <button>Contact Seller</button>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="content-box" *ngIf="isLoading">
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
</div>
```

The {{isLoading}} value displays fine and will show TRUE or FALSE correctly on the page, but none of the object properties will render.  I can console log the object and get all the properties. As you can see in the console log, it looks like my object is held within an array but I'm not sure how that's happening or how to address that item.

[Page with visible {{isLoading}} but non-rendered object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYGyd.png)

When I console.log JSON.stringify(l) this is what I get:
[JSON.stringify of the object in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8HoK.png)

I tried to have an object display in HTML from an Angular component but it is not visible even though it is available in the console log.

Here is the listing service that returns a single 'Listing' item in the 'getListingById' method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Listing } from './types';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


const httpOptions={
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ListingsService {

  constructor(
    private http:HttpClient,
  ) { }
  getListings():Observable<Listing[]>{
    return this.http.get<Listing[]>('/api/listings');
  }

  getListingById(id:string):Observable<Listing>{
    return this.http.get<Listing>(`/api/listings/${id}`);
  }

  addViewToListing(id:string):Observable<Listing>{
    return this.http.post<Listing>(
      `/api/listings/${id}/add-view`,
      {},
      httpOptions
    )
  }


}
```

if I add a

```
 tag and json pipe the object, I get the correct output:
```

```
<pre>{{listing | json}}</pre>
```

generates this on the page:

`{
    "id": "123",
    "name": "guitar",
    "description": "My Old Guitar, plays fine",
    "price": 200,
    "userId": "12345",
    "views": 78
  }
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access your array like an object.

Replacing

```
      this.listing = l;
```

by

```
      this.listing = l[0];
```

Will fix your problem.

I suggest using an ngFor* in order to loop over your listing items.

Comment: The 'l' object returned by my listing service is a single listing and not an array.  I get an error when trying to address it that way:  "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Listing'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'Listing'.ts(7053)"

Comment: it's a bit weird considering you screenshot of console shows "array" with exactly 1 item accessible through key 0. can you update your question with missing code ?

Comment: I agree.  I will update above and show my listing service that returns a single listing.  When I try to use an ngFor on the object I also get an error: Type 'Listing' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2322)
listing-detail-page.component.ts(7, 15): Error occurs in the template of component ListingDetailPageComponent.

Comment: is it a typescript error ? If that's the case, it means that your api returns an array, but as you typed "Listing" and not "Listing[]" in "this.http.get<Listing>(`/api/listings/${id}`);", your compiler says nope, i expect an object, not an array. So you either fix your API, or change your code to Listing[] in order to be able to use it as an array.

Comment: You win the golden ticket!  My api was returning an array. Please take my upvote and appreciation!